# How do I use SQL to sequentially number events based on event type?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequential-number

I am trying to figure out the number of days something occurred for each "event type." For example, I have several users, several event types and dates. I want to add a column for the "Days Since Last Event" (see image). What is the SQL syntax for this (specifically Snowflake)? The image shows exactly what I am trying to do but I created that example in Excel.

[Output Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA1ao.png)

Comment: HI , from the  information that you have give it looks like you could use DATEDIFF function, but to give you a more correct solution, could you please give us the table structure and some sample data.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the image, there is sample data there. I basically want a new column where if event type hasnt changed, take the count + 1, if the event type has changed, start count over at 1.

Comment: I don't know that I can use DATEDIFF function because I am not basing it on dates, just whether the value in an alternate, previous row is the same or different

Answer (score 0):

Using [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html), [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html), [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html), [DATEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html), [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html), [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html)

a long winded set of steps looks like:

```
SELECT 
   user,
   type,
   dates,
   lead(type)over(partition by user order by dates) as lead_event,
   iff(lead_event != type, dates, null) as diff_event_date,
   first_value(dates)over(partition by user order by dates) as first_user_date   
   lag(diff_event_date) ignore nulls over (partition by user order by dates) as last_event_date,
   NVL(last_event_date, dateadd(day,-1,first_user_date)) AS date_of_true_interest
   ​datediff(day, date_of_true_interest, dates) as "days since last event"
FROM data
ORDER BY 1,3
```

but that will not work. so if  we need to shuffle the second lag into a second stage of logic. thus:

```
SELECT 
   user,
   type,
   dates,
   lag(diff_event_date) ignore nulls over (partition by user order by dates) as last_event_date,
   NVL(last_event_date, dateadd(day,-1,first_user_date)) AS date_of_true_interest,
   datediff(day, date_of_true_interest, dates) as "days since last event"
FROM (
    SELECT 
       user,
       type,
       dates,
       lead(type)over(partition by user order by dates) as lead_event,
       iff(lead_event != type, dates, null) as diff_event_date,
       first_value(dates)over(partition by user order by dates) as first_user_date   
    FROM data
)
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

and that's ugly, so another layer to tidy up.

```
SELECT 
   user,
   type,
   dates,
   datediff(day, date_of_true_interest, dates) as "days since last event"
FROM (
    SELECT 
       user,
       type,
       dates,
       lag(diff_event_date) ignore nulls over (partition by user order by dates) as last_event_date,
       NVL(last_event_date, dateadd(day,-1,first_user_date)) AS date_of_true_interest
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           user,
           type,
           dates,
           lead(type)over(partition by user order by dates) as lead_event,
           iff(lead_event != type, dates, null) as diff_event_date,
           first_value(dates)over(partition by user order by dates) as first_user_date
        FROM data
    ) 
)
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

and mix with some `data`

```
WITH data AS (
    select * from values 
        (12345,'active',to_date('1/15/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'active',to_date('1/16/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'active',to_date('1/17/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'dormant',to_date('1/18/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'dormant',to_date('1/19/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'churned',to_date('1/20/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'churned',to_date('1/21/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (12345,'churned',to_date('1/22/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (39498,'active',to_date('1/15/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (39498,'active',to_date('1/16/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (39498,'dormant',to_date('1/17/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
        (39498,'churned',to_date('1/18/21', 'MM/DD/YY'))
    v( user, type, dates)
)
```

we get the results:

| USER | TYPE | DATES | days since last event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | active | 2021-01-15 | 1 |
| 12345 | active | 2021-01-16 | 2 |
| 12345 | active | 2021-01-17 | 3 |
| 12345 | dormant | 2021-01-18 | 1 |
| 12345 | dormant | 2021-01-19 | 2 |
| 12345 | churned | 2021-01-20 | 1 |
| 12345 | churned | 2021-01-21 | 2 |
| 12345 | churned | 2021-01-22 | 3 |
| 39498 | active | 2021-01-15 | 1 |
| 39498 | active | 2021-01-16 | 2 |
| 39498 | dormant | 2021-01-17 | 1 |
| 39498 | churned | 2021-01-18 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

In the comment "if event type hasn't changed, take the count + 1, if the event type has changed, start count over at 1", this is important statement and can be translated as a window function on event type and then using `row_number` function.

There's an interesting window function called `conditional_change_event`
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html
which will help with the changes of current row vs previous row.

Note that  there's an `order by` clause in `conditional_change_event` which makes us introduce an `autoincrement` id column. That said let's get into action with some sql queries

Table creation with sample values:

```
create or replace temporary table _temp (
 id int autoincrement,
 user int,
 _type varchar,
 dates date
);

insert into _temp(user, _type, dates)
values (12345,'active',to_date('1/15/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'active',to_date('1/16/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'active',to_date('1/17/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'dormant',to_date('1/18/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'dormant',to_date('1/19/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'churned',to_date('1/20/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'churned',to_date('1/21/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(12345,'churned',to_date('1/22/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(39498,'active',to_date('1/15/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(39498,'active',to_date('1/16/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(39498,'dormant',to_date('1/17/21', 'MM/DD/YY')),
(39498,'churned',to_date('1/18/21', 'MM/DD/YY'));
```

Goal

```
with event_changes as (
  select *,
  conditional_change_event(_type) over (order by id) as type_changes
  from _temp
)
select *, 
row_number() over(partition by _type, type_changes order by id) as days_since_last_event
from event_changes
order by id;
```

Output

```
  ID    USER    _TYPE   DATES   TYPE_CHANGES    DAYS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT
   1    12345   active  2021-01-15  0   1
   2    12345   active  2021-01-16  0   2
   3    12345   active  2021-01-17  0   3
   4    12345   dormant 2021-01-18  1   1
   5    12345   dormant 2021-01-19  1   2
   6    12345   churned 2021-01-20  2   1
   7    12345   churned 2021-01-21  2   2
   8    12345   churned 2021-01-22  2   3
   9    39498   active  2021-01-15  3   1
  10    39498   active  2021-01-16  3   2
  11    39498   dormant 2021-01-17  4   1
  12    39498   churned 2021-01-18  5   1
```